# Passing arguments in constructor with boost factory

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, factory

I am fairly new with the whole factory implementation and as a result maybe my question will sound wrong and not very well defined. 
So, with few words I want to have a boost factoty in order to initialize a banch fo derived classes and so far I have managed to do so for classes with empty constructors. Let me present to my current boost factory implementation for two small classes:

**Base.h:**

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "boost/function.hpp"

class base {

protected:
    typedef boost::function <base *()> basefactory;

public:
      base();
      virtual ~base();

     int a;

     static std::map<std::string,base::basefactory>& b_factory();

  };

#endif /* BASE_H_ */
```

**Base.cpp:**

```
#include "base.h"

base::base() {
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

base::~base() {
  // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

static std::map<std::string,base::basefactory>& base::b_factory()
{
  static std::map<std::string,base::basefactory>* ans =
  new std::map<std::string,base::basefactory>();
  return *ans;
}
```

**Derived.h :**

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H_
#define DERIVED_H_

#include "boost/function.hpp"
#include "boost/functional/factory.hpp"
#include <iostream>

#include "base.h"

class derived : public base {
     public:
         derived();
         virtual ~derived();

          int b;

          static class _init {
            public:
               _init() {
                       base::b_factory()["derived"] = boost::factory<derived*>();
                       }
           }_initializer;

 };

 #endif /* DERIVED_H_ */
```

**Derived.cpp:**

```
#include "derived.h"

derived::derived() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

derived::~derived() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

derived::_init derived::_initializer;
```

So, the above desplayed code works just fine for empty constructor of the classes, but I am very unsure how to modify the code in case the base and derived class constructors need to receive arguments. More specifically let's say that I want to have the base constructor:

```
base(int alpha) { 
a = alpha;
}
```

And also the derived constructor:

```
derived(int alpha, int beta) : base( alpha ) // in order to pass the argument alpha to the base class
{ 
    b = beta;
}
```

So, as said above I am really unsure what modifications I need to do in order to manage to have the above boost factory implementation working for my code.
I know there are some posts in here in elsewhere online for parametrized constructors but they didn't manage to make me properly understand how to do it myself and that's why I made this post her.
Any kind of help/suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: [OT]: `static std::map<std::string,base::basefactory> ans; return ans;` is enough for `b_factory`. `new` unneeded.

Comment: Do you want to pass argument to your factory ? or do you want to bind some value ? So do you want to call `base::b_factory().at("derived")(alpha, beta)`, or that `base::b_factory().at("derived")()` calls `derived(42, 51)` ?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, I think for my purpose I want to pass arguments to the factory, in the sense that when initializing the objects with the factory command, for example in the simple case without parameters in the constructor:
base example = base::b_factory()["derived"]();
I want the user to be able to pass the values that will be used for the constructor parameters (int alpha and int beta in our case)

Comment: Any further suggestion maybe..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a factory which takes 2 arguments, you may do:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::function<base* (int, int)>> factories;
factories["derived"] = boost::bind(boost::factory<derived*>(), _1, _2);

std::unique_ptr<base> b{factories.at("derived")(42, 52)};
```

If you want to fix arguments, you may do

```
std::map<std::string, boost::function<base* ()>> factories;
factories["derived"] = boost::bind(boost::factory<derived*>(), 42, 52);
std::unique_ptr<base> b{factories.at("derived")()};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f59506c51c52b67)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help now everything works properly!