# Boost Factory compile error

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-functional

Trying to implement abstract factory with Boost Factory, classes of the hierarchy have c-tor params, already looked this discussion: [Passing arguments in constructor with boost factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137117/passing-arguments-in-constructor-with-boost-factory)

My example is the following:

```
struct base {
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

struct derived1 : public base {
    derived1(int a1, int a2) {}
    virtual ~derived1() = default;
    virtual void method() {}
};
```

Create factory and try to create an instance

```
std::map<uint8_t, boost::function<base*(int, int)>> my_factory;
my_factory[0] = boost::bind(boost::factory<derived1*>(), _1, _2) ;
std::unique_ptr<base> derived_instance(my_factory.at(0)(1, 2));
```

Problem it does not compile at all with the error in boost::bind `cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &'`

I understand the nature of the error, boost::bind expect non-const reference for some reasons, but I'm passing rvalue that could not be referenced. Of course, after changing constructor params `derived1` to references everything compiles but it would look ugly. What is correct usage of this pattern?

More abstract question - is it worth to use Boost Factory with C++14? Implementations seems a bit out-of-date, I expected something variadic-based

C++ Compiler Visual Studio 2015

Boost 1.61

Comment: Works fine in GCC and Clang.  What if you do this: `int x = 1, y = 2;
std::unique_ptr<base> derived_instance(my_factory.at(0)(boost::ref(x), boost::ref(y)));` ?

Comment: Nope. It works:

`std::map<uint8_t, boost::function<base*(int&, int&)>> my_factory; 
    my_factory[0] = boost::bind(boost::factory<derived1*>(), _1, _2) ; 
    int x = 1, y = 2; 
    std::unique_ptr<base> derived_instance(my_factory.at(0)(x, y));`
But looks terrible

Comment: Well it's some sort of problem with your compiler.  I don't think that workaround is so bad.

Comment: Yep, I'd just create a wrapper to hide it :)